# Shortcut for automatic import of a class in WebStorm for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

I was watching a [tutorial video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-injecting-a-service) of Angular2 and the guy typed `@Injectable()` then with some black magic a line appeared on top

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
```

How did he do this, what type of sorcery is this ?

Comment: I guess this was WebStorm? If so, it is smart enough to do it for you. Not surprisingly for the probably best available IDE. However it's not big deal, it just analyzes  and caches all typing information and imports.

Comment: i know, i'm just asking what type of short cut should i use ? i heard the guy in the video pressing some keys

Comment: You don't use any shortcut, it just checks if you don't have a sympol imported already and if it's exported by some module WebStorm automatically adds it for you.

Comment: when I type @Injectable i don't get the dropdown choices

Comment: here is the video i'm talking about https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-injecting-a-service minute 0:20

Comment: Make sure you enable auto-import  feature. Go to Editor > General > Auto Import (TypeScript).

Answer (score 5):

He (John Lindquist) used <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> (the shortcut in Default keymap -- may differ if you're using different keymap) to bring the Quick Fix menu (also can be triggered by clicking on light bulb icon).

Once menu is shown he used "Add import statement" entry (quick fix) from that menu.

---

RE: keymap -- you may check and assign different shortcut for that menu -- just use `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and look for `Show Intention Actions` action (hint: use search boxes to quickly narrow the list).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the greatest shortcuts in ***WebStorm*** editor.

Following below steps:

- Open WebStorm code editor.
- Preferences
- Editor
- General
- Auto Import
- Mark : show Import Pop up
- Mark : Merge imports for symbols from the same module.

Ok.

Imagine you want to use Validators in your form. You are typing `Validators.required` and then it shows the `Validators` word in red colour because it needs to be imported to the angular/forms.
***Double click*** on the word and press ***option+enter***. it automatically imports:

`import {Validators} from "@angular/forms";`

The reason that I asked you to also
*mark : Merge imports for symbols from the same module* is:

Imagine you have already imported `Validators` from `@angular/forms` and now you want to add FormGroup which also needs to be imported from `@angular/forms`. What is happening now is it does not add another extra import line for each of them separately but is just adding to the available one.

```
import { Validators , FormGroup } from "@angular/forms"
```